# Unable to define top level field "automatic" in a chef knife search node

Tags: search, chef-infra, knife

I would like to specifically use the automatic_name:server in the command line "knife search node".

Any advise on how to accomplish this, would be greatly appreciated.

When coding against the server, node.automatic['name'] is available. Also, when exporting to json, the jq query shows that automatic is part of the server data held within chef.   So, not sure why knife search node does not recognize/honor automatic.

The following shows that the knife search does not return when automatic is declared.

```
# knife search node -i "automatic_name:server"
0 items found

# knife search node -i "name:server"
1 items found

# knife node show server -Fj -l > server.json
# jq '.automatic.name' server.json
"server"
```

Thanks in advance.
wcm

Comment: @seshadri_c Thanks for the response.  We were able to find the root cause that made the name attribute missing in the automatic attribute.  /etc/hosts order was incorrect.

However, We just ran into a similar issue with roles.  There is already a chef-server ticket opened on adding the ability to search for top level node attributes  since 2015.

https://github.com/chef/chef-server/issues/303

Answer (score 0):

The `knife search` subcommand searches the data "indexed" by the Chef server. Also the multi-level (deep) [JSON structure](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_search/#nested-fields) is flattened to top-level:

> A nested field appears deeper in the JSON data structure. For example, information. about a network interface might be several layers deep: node['network']['interfaces']['en1']. When nested fields are present in a JSON structure, Chef Infra Client will extract those nested fields to the top-level, flattening them into compound fields that support wildcard search patterns.

Consider a node's following "automatic" attributes in JSON:

```json
  "automatic": {
    "kernel": {
      "os_info": {
        "truncated": "lines",
        "build_number": "17763",
        "code_set": "1252",
        "truncated": "lines"
      }
    }
  }
```

If I wanted to search on `build_number` or `code_set`, I would search it as (if) it is available at top-level:

```
~$ knife search node "build_number:17763"
1 items found

~$ knife search node "code_set:1252"
1 items found
```

In your case also, "automatic" is being honored. The `server` information is flattened to the top-level, and is searchable without having to prefix it with `automatic`.